# Confused by Aws SES timestamp, how does it work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I configured my SES notifications sent to SNS service. When I send email from SES using python, SNS send me notifications about email is sent & delivered with timestamps. But at that time I didn't receive email at all while Aws SES notifies me it's delivered. I received the email few minutes after that. Anyone can explain how these timestamps works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamps are when SES successfully sent the email message but those timestamps have nothing to do with how long it takes your mail client to check the mail server for new messages and download the messages to the client, or even how long your mail server takes to route the message to the right inbox (although that should be very fast).

Consider the case where your may client is configured to check for new emails every 5 minutes:
**Minute 1**:  SES successfully delivers the email.
**Minute 2**:  SNS delivers the notification to you with Timestamp 1.
**Minute 5**:  Your email client checks the mail server and detects there is a new message, and downloads it.

You will see the message in your email client at Minute 5 although SES delivered it at Minute 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are actually 2 separate events and 2 different timestamps. `Sent` and `Delivery`. I thought when amazon send email to client's email server it returns timestamp of `Sent` and when actually client server received, it returns `Delivery` timestamp. But my guess was wrong.
So what's the difference between `Send` and `Delivery` timestamp if it doesn't count how long it took when client received email? What is it counting?

Comment: I think the Send timestamp is when the sender sent the message to SES and the Delivery timestamp is when SES was able to successfully deliver the mail to the recipient mail server.  There can be a difference in the two timestamps that can be attributed to SES processing time, a temporary issue w/ the recipient e.g. full mailbox (SES will attempt to resend a few time), etc.

Comment: I'm curious, does the processingTimeMillis field capture the difference between the 2 timestamps?

Comment: Ah that would makes sense, yes `processingTimeMillis` is difference between `Send` and `Delivery` timestamps.

Comment: @ShinebayarG Please don't forget to accept the answer, if you agree.